# Which Language to use to create Graph Data from MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, html, web

I have been developing VB.Net Windows Application Utilities to help me process Data from SQL now for about a year, and I would now like to Start using the Web to re-write some of my applications which display Data from MySql Tables. Where should I start? What Language PHP? Python? Javascript?, HTML5?  Just looking for a few examples and some resources to get started on the right track?

Thanks in Advance Guys !

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.

You will not use just ONE language to build applications to the web. You'll need a language to the server side and a language to the client side (the web browser).
There are many options on the server side. I, personally, use PHP and C#.NET with the ASP.NET MVC platform. Since you are familiar with Visual Basic, I recommend that you continue using VB, and just plug it to some web specific platform, like ASP.NET MVC as i have mentioned. Here is a tutorial: [Click here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/230/getting-started-with-asp-net-mvc-5-using-visual-basic)

In the client side, you need to use HTML and Javascript. I have just one observation: HTML5 is NOT a programming language, but a markup language. The PROGRAMMING language for the client side, kinda MUST BE javascript ;)
Here you can find some valuable resources about javascript: [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript) and [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/paths/javascript). And you will find some tutorials about HTML and CSS too ;)
Good luck in your journey. Sure you will like it! :D

Answer (score 1):

I've always been a fan of http://jpgraph.net/ as far back as 2003.  It's pretty straightforward to use in PHP.  Pull your data from the database anyway you choose, stuff the result into an array, then apply JpGraph functions to derive charts/graphs from the array data. Website contains lots of examples, HowTo's, and documentation.

Comment: Hi There, I have since installed JPGraph, but finally seem to have all installed correctly but when I try and path to some of the examples I get nothing at apart from this Error : You can see on 
http://hcs-it.com/realtime/Examples/accbarex1.php

Chosen locale file ("lang/en.inc.php") for error messages does not exist or is not readable for the PHP process. Please make sure that the file exists and that the file permissions are such that the PHP process is allowed to read this file.

Comment: I have added the lang folder but now get no Error At All ?? How can I debug this if no error is showing?? http://hcs-it.com/accbarex1.php

I Added Hello World to the Top of the PHP to make sure it was Updating but Still nothing ? Maybe should start a new thread for this?

Comment: "The requested URL /realtime/Examples/accbarex1.php was not found on this server."  It will be a bit difficult to help you debug a program if the file no longer exists!  :)

Comment: Very sorry I removed this, as this was resolved. It was due to the fact that I have a linux restrictdir on my web server and Files must be in root folder of executing php code.  Thanks Though

Comment: no problem.  hope you got it working!